# WP7 Application is being deactivated with no reason 10 seconds after navigating to a page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

A WP 7.1 project starts with a Page that host a Panorama control. At some point user click on a ListBox, and this navigates the application to a details page.

In case the debugger is attached, everything stays on the screen as it should. But If I test an application either in emulator, or on the phone without a debugger, approximately in 5-10 seconds after the details page navigation, an application gets deactivated.

No unhanded exception, not closing, but deactivated even is raised. I have placed a message boxes in each of "exit handlers" to know exactly what happens and found out that it is deactivation.

No user input takes place after navigation and before the deactivation.

What may be the reason for such "no interaction" deactivation?

I don't call no "deactivate" requests from code.

**Additional info:**
Details page is bound to a sample view model that is obtained via MVVM Light ViewModel locator. View model locator gets it from ninject kernel that is a static public property of an App object(*Yes, I have made IOC container publicly available via App property. I know it probably is a horrible practice, but I doubt the problem is linked to that*).  The page initializes just fine and displays all the data from a sample view model class. It almost seems like an app is deactivated due to inactivity, but there is no such thing in WP7 as far as I know.

**UPDATE**

A deactivation takes place exactly 10 seconds afer I call this line:

```
((PhoneApplicationFrame)(Application.Current.RootVisual)).Navigate(new Uri("/Views/BookDetailsView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

from a view model of a main application view. The problem view is a details view, not the main one.

The constructor for BookDetailsView is empty (default):

```
public partial class BookDetailsView : UserControl
    {
        public BookDetailsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The XAML for the view binds it's datacontext to a property of a mvvm light view model locator:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=BookDetails}"
```

The `Locator` resource is decleared in App.xaml and points to ViewModelLocator.cs.

The property that provides datacontext for a problem view is:

```
public static IBookDetailsViewModel BookDetailsStatic
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public IBookDetailsViewModel BookDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return BookDetailsStatic;
            }
        }
```

The `BookDetailsStatic` is initialized from the IoC container call in the ViewModelLocator ctor:

```
BookDetailsStatic = App.Kernel.Get<IBookDetailsViewModel>();
```

In a any scenario the call to get an IBookDetailsViewModel returns an instance of a

```
public class SampleBookDetailsViewModel: IBookDetailsViewModel
```

which has an empty constructor and a bunch of properties.

**SOLVED**
My view, that I have been navigating to, was declared as a UserControl, and should have been as PhoneApplicationPage.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on this line `private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)` in your `App.xaml` code behind.

Comment: For what reason? As I mention, in debug mode the problem doesn't take place. Application_UnhandledException has a MessageBox.Show in it, but no exceptions take place, just plain deactivation.

Comment: your right, without seeing the code, it's hard to tell what's going on, maybe you can try commenting out your code just to find out where exactly causes this issue.

Comment: What happens in the detail page? Have you looked at memory usage? (either by adding on screen counters or via the profiler.)

Comment: @MattLacey I thought about it, but I have no experience in profiling on WP7 so I didn't do it just yet. I was kind of expecting an answer in a form: Deactivation can happen because of a memory leak. Try to profile an app.

Comment: Could your constructor still be running? It must finish within 10 seconds or else your app will get killed. (That's why you should never put a messagebox inside the constructor)

Comment: @willmel, a deactivation happens exactly 10 seconds after I call the navigation from a view model of an initial window. I have shown how I call the navigation in the update to the question.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov That's in the constructor?

Comment: @willmel, navigation call takes place as a chain reaction to a user clicking on a list box item. User click on the item - code-behind selection_changed event is invoked -> code behind calls the method in VM -> VM method calls the Navigate.

Comment: Can you post the constructor for BookDetailsView? And if the VM for it is created via the the DataContext in XAML, that too.

Comment: @willmel, Updated with the constructors you mentioned. Basically two are empty constructors, but are linked to an execution chain in a tricky way.

Comment: Hey, the problem is solved - I was navigating to a UserControl, not a PhoneApplicationPage, and that is why I was getting kicked out. Thanks willmel. Eventually you have led me to this. If you care about reputation, you should post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, nah, but post it as an answer for yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BookDetailsView` was decleared as a `UserControl`.

Navigating to a `UserControl` deactivates an application in 10 seconds.

Changing the type of a view to `PhoneApplicationPage` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing what's on the page, but you could be hitting the memory limit.

In general, you can consider the memory limit to be 90mb, but you're better off checking [DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationmemoryusagelimit.aspx) and [DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationcurrentmemoryusage%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and possibly displaying it on screen every half second or so to debug.

You can also try the profiler, assuming it doesn't affect the repro.

Comment: Just tried it. Reports only 16MB mem usage right before the moment of deactivation. Deactivation Event Args should have included the deactivation reason, this would make life much easier =)